# How to load data from CSV to Hive external table (Avro format)?

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro, large-files, beeline

I try to build a beeline script to load a CSV file stored in HDFS to an external table in Hive. First I create an empty external table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.table
(column string)
STORED AS AVRO
LOCATION '/foo/bar'
```

After that I checked if the table was created. And it was. I already loaded a CSV file into HDFS with:

```
hdfs dfs -put test.csv /temp/raw_csv
```

Now I want to load/insert (whatever) this CSV data to the external Hive table, but stored in Avro fromat (like defined in the create script). I tried it with this line:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/temp/raw_csv/test.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE db.table
```

This line runs without an error, see the cmd output here:

> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .>  . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . .> INFO  : Compiling
> command(queryId=hive_20201201130808_4120504b-6799-4833-83e7-5fa8ff8c6ca8):
> LOAD DATA INPATH '/temp/raw_csv/test.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE
> db.table INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed INFO  : Returning Hive
> schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:null, properties:null) INFO  : Completed
> compiling
> command(queryId=hive_20201201130808_4120504b-6799-4833-83e7-5fa8ff8c6ca8);
> Time taken: 0.427 seconds INFO  : Executing
> command(queryId=hive_20201201130808_4120504b-6799-4833-83e7-5fa8ff8c6ca8):
> LOAD DATA INPATH '/temp/raw_csv/test.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE
> db.table INFO  : Starting task [Stage-0:MOVE] in serial mode INFO  :
> Loading data to table db.table from hdfs://temp/raw_csv/test.csv  INFO
> : Starting task [Stage-1:STATS] in serial mode INFO  : Table db.table
> stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=45981179] INFO  : Completed executing
> command(queryId=hive_20201201130808_4120504b-6799-4833-83e7-5fa8ff8c6ca8);
> Time taken: 0.376 seconds INFO  : OK No rows affected (0.87 seconds)

But if I want to select the table with following line, I get an error:

```
select * FROM db.test;
```

> INFO  : Compiling
> command(queryId=hive_20201201131414_79187a87-c5e6-4b54-aecc-54c15d9a4bfa):
> select * FROM db.test INFO  : Semantic Analysis Completed INFO  :
> Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:column,
> type:string, comment:null) INFO  : Completed compiling
> command(queryId=hive_20201201131414_79187a87-c5e6-4b54-aecc-54c15d9a4bfa);
> Time taken: 0.243 seconds INFO  : Executing
> command(queryId=hive_20201201131414_79187a87-c5e6-4b54-aecc-54c15d9a4bfa):
> select * FROM db.test INFO  : Completed executing
> command(queryId=hive_20201201131414_79187a87-c5e6-4b54-aecc-54c15d9a4bfa);
> Time taken: 0.006 seconds INFO  : OK Error: java.io.IOException:
> java.io.IOException: Not a data file. (state=,code=0)

Is it possible to load data from CSV to Hive Avro table with an beeline command? And/Or what will be a better way to load this data? I normally load 1-100 million rows of data.

Answer (score 4):

It does not work that way. LOAD command does not transform data, it just moves file into table location.

**If you want to convert from `CSV` to `AVRO`**, then do these steps:

1. [Create csv table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54463863/2700344)
2. Put file directly into table location using `hdfs dfs -put`  or use

   LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH  'local/path/to/csv'  OVERWRITE INTO TABLE db.csv_table
3. create avro table
4. Use Hive to load data from csv table to avro

   insert overwrite table avro_table
   select ... from csv_table

SerDe is responsible for reading and writing data files, it is being used when you create table with some specific SerDe and selecting or inserting the data. LOAD does know nothing about file schema and does not use SerDe. In the last step (4) Hive will read csv table and insert the same data into Avro table, it will use SerDe specified in both tables DDL for serializing data to Avro format and de-serializing from csv.

Alternatively you can convert CSV file to AVRO file using [csv2avro tool](https://github.com/sspinc/csv2avro) or some other tool, then load it into AVRO table location.

**If you have no purpose to convert from CSV to Avro**, only to load data to the table to be able to select it, then all you need is to create CSV table and put data files into it's location (step 1 and 2).

Comment: this is the answer man. Load just move the data. You need to make first the scheme.. what you can do is adapt your table to the data scheme or process the data first