# Error in data while creating external tables in Athena

Tags: csv, hive, amazon-athena, external-tables, hive-serde

I have my data in CSV format in the below form:

Id   -> tinyint

Name -> String

```
  Id  Name
  1   Alex
  2   Sam
```

When I export the CSV file to S3 and create an Athena table, the data transform into the following format.

```
 Id   Name
 1    "Alex"
 2    "Sam"
```

How do I get rid of the double quotes while creating the table?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By default if SerDe is not specified, Athena is using LasySimpleSerDe, it does not support quoted values and reads quotes as a part of value. If your CSV file contains quoted values, use [OpenCSVSerde](https://github.com/ogrodnek/csv-serde) (specify correct separatorChar if it is not comma):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable(
  id   tinyint,
  Name string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"', 
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
)
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/mytable/' 
;
```

Read the manuals: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html
See also this answer about [data types in OpenCSVSerDe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50001812/2700344)